# DockYards Ember-Validations: Error when including Mix-In

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.js 1.0.0-rc.1 and have just started playing with [DockYards Ember Validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations).

However when I add the mixin-in to my Controllers:

```
App.ApiLocateLedController = App.ApiObjectController.extend(
    Ember.Validations.Mixin,
    {
    ...
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('errors', <Ember.Validations.Errors:ember431>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ApiLocateLedController:ember432>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

I have tried every version of Ember-validations on git and I get the same error.

I get the feeling I am overlooking something simple. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ember-validations mixin is used on your model not your controller, like

```
var App.User = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {});
```